# Which properties are invariant for totally ordered sets?

Tags: order-theory

I am asked to find some number of totally ordered sets such that no one is isomorphic to a subset of another. To do this I wanted to think about the properties that are preserved for totally ordered sets.

Two examples that I've thought of are the minimal and maximal element. If a totally set has either of these, then any totally ordered set isomorphic to it must also have the same thing.

Another thing is possibly denseness. For example $\mathbb Q$ cannot be isomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb N$ because $\mathbb N$ is not dense in itself. However, I have a gut feeling that something may go wrong for denseness, even though I feel like it is preserved.

Are there any more properties other than this that are preserved under isomorphism between totally ordered sets? Thank you!

Comment: This is a bit vague. Meanwhile, the only thing that seems to be wrong in your comparison between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb N$ is that, although $\mathbb Q$ can't be isomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb N$, it is certainly true that the converse occurs.

Comment: Notice that you're only allowed one *well*-order, since for every pair $W, X$ of different well-orders, either $W$ is order isomorphic to an initial segment of $X$, or vice versa.

Comment: Q is dense.  The subset N is not.

Comment: @amrsa yes I know, I was merely highlighting that it is a property maintained under isomorphism.

Comment: This is really not a very useful way to approach the original problem. As for that problem, it’s not hard to find two linear orders, neither of which embeds in the other (e.g., any infinite well order and its reversal), or even three ($\omega_1$, $\omega_1^*$, and $\Bbb R$), but beyond that it gets harder. Adding an [Aronszajn line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aronszajn_line) to the last set brings it to four.